# How to define a hypothesis of Bayes Theorem in this problem?

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

While reading [Think Bayes](http://allendowney.github.io/ThinkBayes2/index.html) by Allen Downey, I encountered an exercise problem bellow.

> Exercise: M&M's are small candy-coated chocolates that come in a variety of colors.
> Mars, Inc., which makes M&M's, changes the mixture of colors from time to time. In 1995, they introduced blue M&M's.
>
> In 1994, the color mix in a bag of plain M&M's was 30% Brown, 20% Yellow, 20% Red, 10% Green, 10% Orange, 10% Tan.
>
> In 1996, it was 24% Blue , 20% Green, 16% Orange, 14% Yellow, 13% Red, 13% Brown.
>
> Suppose a friend of mine has two bags of M&M's, and he tells me that one is from 1994 and one from 1996. He won't tell me which is which, but he gives me one M&M from each bag. One is yellow and one is green. What is the probability that the yellow one came from the 1994 bag?

I though that there were two hypotheses: one was that the yellow M&M was from a bag from 1994 and the other was that the yellow M&M was from a bag from 1996. Although I was not really sure about an evidence, I guessed that the evidence is that one M&M is yellow and the other is green.

However, according to the solution, those hypotheses are defined like below.

> Hypotheses
>
> A: yellow from 94, green from 96
>
> B: yellow from 96, green from 94

Then, prior probability for each hypothesis is 1/2. I also do not understand why P(yellow from 94 and green from 96) is 1/2. Should it be 0.2*0.2 = 0.04?

I think that I miss something very significant in my understanding.

**My questions:**

1. Why do I need to include the green M&M information in the
   hypotheses?
2. Why is the prior probability for each hypothesis
   1/2?
3. What would be the correct evidence I should use in this problem? In my understanding, hypotheses must not include any additional information. But, hypotheses in the solution certainly include additional information that one M&M is yellow and the other is green.

Comment: You have observed both the yellow and the green so you should take them into account.  Presumably the yellow and green were randomly selected, one from each bag (if they were deliberately chosen by your friend, then all bets are off).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740683/urn-problem-why-isnt-pyellow-mm-is-from-1994-bag-pbag-from-1996green-m https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924904/urn-type-problem-with-bayes-theorem-and-mms-dont-understand-how-probability https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381148/mms-bag-a-is-20-yellow-bag-b-is-13-yellow-you-get-a-yellow-and-green-mm-fr